# How do I make two javascript function calls in an inline onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<script>
function delay (URL) {
setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 2000);
}</script>
```

Then the following in the `<body>` element:

```
<img src="small_rabbit.png" onclick="href= \"javascript:delay('URL') \"; showBunnyPicture('bunny')" alt="Small rabbit picture" />
```

which will show a picture of a rabbit when the user clicks a button and then the page will link to a URL after a delay.

However I can't see how to format this line of code with all the " and ' in so that it works. I've tried escape characters but am falling short. Can anyone see a simple solution please?

Comment: can you post full code ?

Comment: Which html element you are using??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="delay('URL'); showBunnyPicture('bunny');" >CLICK HERE</a>
```

removed the href=" "

Comment: How would you propose that this be tested? The OP didn't provide either of the functions that are being called. This is the correct syntax for calling multiple functions from the function defined by an onclick attribute though.

Comment: That solved it - thanks!
Wood for the trees. Yeah, the onclick event was triggering the loading of a new page so I didn't need the anchor tag inside it.

Comment: Code I used is 
    <img src="bunny_picture.png" onclick="delay('URL'); showBunnyPicture('bunny');" />